# JavaScript For Loop To Fill In Array

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object (Shopify.checkout.line_items) that contains an array. I want to fill out an array (items) with this data.

The below is a simplified version of the code with the core problem that you can't just shove a for loop in the middle of an array literal:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'transaction_id': '{{ order.order_number }}',
    'items': [
      for (var line_item_count = 0; line_item_count < Shopify.checkout.line_items.length; line_item_count++){
        { 'id':
          '{{ item.variant_id }}',
          'quantity': Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count].quantity,
          'price': Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count].line_price
        },
        Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count] += 1;
    ]
  });
```

This is the output I'm looking to achieve:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'transaction_id': '123',
    'items': [
        { 'id':
          '53465346346',
          'quantity': 2,
          'price': 4
        },
        { 'id':
          '245643745764',
          'quantity': 1,
          'price': 1
        }
    ]
  });
```

How do I fill out an array literal with a correct JavaScript loop?

Comment: _"I have a JavaScript object (Shopify.checkout.line_items) that contains an array."_ Are you sure `Shopify.checkout.line_items` is an object and not an array? For me it looks like an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a loop in an array literal but you can use array methods to achieve the some result:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'transaction_id': '{{ order.order_number }}',
    'items': Array(Shopify.checkout.line_items.length).fill(0).map((_, line_item_count) => {
        const result = { 
          'id': '{{ item.variant_id }}',
          'quantity': Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count].quantity,
          'price': Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count].line_price
        };
        Shopify.checkout.line_items[line_item_count] += 1;
        return result;
    })
});
```

`Array(Shopify.checkout.line_items.length)` creates an array with `length` `Shopify.checkout.line_items.length`. `fill(0)` sets each element to `0`. This step is necessary because `map` skips all unset elements. `map(...)` contains the logic from the for loop and returns a new array.

I don't know Shopify but if `Shopify.checkout.line_items` is an array or array-like you can use that array instead of creating a new array and improve the code:

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'transaction_id': '{{ order.order_number }}',
    'items': Shopify.checkout.line_items.map((el, idx, arr) => {
        arr[idx]++;
        return {
          'id': '{{ item.variant_id }}',
          'quantity': el.quantity,
          'price': el.line_price
        };
    })
});
```